# Call two functions from a change in input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, aws-amplify

I am writing a script where I want to execute two functions when the user input in the input box -

1. Assign the input value to a variable (MeetingID)
2. Call a function which uses the above variable in intervals

Below is my script -

```
 function MyEditor({ signOut, user }){

const[value,setValue]=React.useState([]);
var MeetingID 


const txnMutation: any = value.map((txn, i) => {
  return `mutation${i}: deleteDatamodel(input: {id: "${txn.id}"}) { id }`;
  });
useEffect(()=>{
    //call api
    //add the function of api here as well
   fetchTrans(meetingID)
  const intervalId = setInterval(()=>{
      fetchTrans()
      
  },1000);
 return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
},[]);

async function fetchTrans(meetingID) {
  try {
    const querysort = Object.assign({},{
      sortDirection : 'ASC' ,type : 'datamodel', filter: {MeetingID:{eq:`${MeetingID}`}} 
    })
    const transData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(datamodel,querysort));
    console.log(transData);
    //const transData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(datamodelByDate,variables));
    const datamodels = transData.data.datamodel.items;
    setValue(datamodels)
    //console.log(transData.data.datamodelByDate.items)
  } catch (err) { console.log('error fetching transcription:', err) }
}

async function handleDelete(){
  const deleteData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(`
  mutation batchMutation {
    ${txnMutation}
  }
`));
  console.log(deleteData)
}

async function getstring(){
  var textToHighlight = value.sort((a, b) => a - b.id).map(transcript => textToHighlight=textToHighlight+transcript.Transcription )
}

const set = new Set(["tech", "deck", "Financial","select","post","social","Sometimes","sick","mad"]);
const arr = value.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
const handleUserInputChange = (e) => {
  MeetingID = e.target.name;
  fetchTrans()
  
};

  function createMarkup(transcript) {
    const words = ["tech", "deck", "financial","test","this is a test transcription","Tech-Debt","Look","Sometimes","together","negotiate","market"];
    let str = `${transcript.createdAt} ${transcript.Transcription}`;
    

    
   
    words.forEach((word) => {
      if (str.includes(word)) {
        str = str.replaceAll(word, `<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">${word}</span>`);
      }
    });
  
    return { __html: str };
  }
  
  return <RightWrapper>
    <Header>
      <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Transcription</Button>
      <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Meeting ID" value={MeetingID} onChange={handleUserInputChange}/>
    </Header>
    
    {arr.map((transcript) => (
  <p
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(transcript)}
    key={transcript.id}
  ></p>
))}
    

      </RightWrapper>;

      
}
```

The problem is that the fetchTrans function is not fetching based on the filter based on the variable input by the user but it fetches previous input. I want that as soon as there is a change in input the fetchTrans function which runs in interval updates its parameter (MeetingID) and fetches based on that.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem was. What's working? What's not?

Comment: @jperl oh ! the problem is that the fetchTrans function is not fetching based on the filter based on the variable input by the user but it fetches previous input. I want that as soon as there is a change in input the fetchTrans function which runs in interval updates its parameter (MeetingID) and fetches based on that.

Comment: Seems like you expect that changing `MeetingID` variable will somehow change your `querysort`. But why would it? `querysort` has been already assigned its value.

Comment: Just move the `querysort` assignment inside the `fetchTrans()` function and pass meetingID as a param to `fetchTrans(meetingID)`. And remove `var MeetingIDi` altogether.

Comment: @SergiyOstrovsky Thank you ! I understood the issue but it seems like my input is not updating the variable MeetingID because if I set the variable to static value its fetching but not by input. I have updated my script. Please have a look.

Comment: @user8112228 if you want to render this variable, you will need to use it with `useState()`. So `[meetingId, setMeetingId] = useState()`, then inside `handleUserInputChange` you have to add `setMeetingId(e.target.name)` and then you can use this variable also in `fetchTrans` I guess. I recommend to read more how React works.